# Accesskey for "enter" keystroke in HTML

Tags: html

What is the accesskey for enter in html?

For example in a button to trigger it using the keystroke "h" it would be accesskey = "h"
however accesskey = "enter" nor accesskey = "Enter" work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use accesskey to trigger a button with `Enter` key

From [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey):

> The attribute value must consist of a single printable character (which includes accented and other characters that can be generated by the keyboard).

You could use js to listen for an enter keypress pretty easily as follows:

```js
const enterBtn = document.getElementById("enter-btn");

enterBtn.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("clicky!"));

window.addEventListener("keypress", ({key}) => {
  if (key == "Enter")
    enterBtn.click();
});
```

```html
<p>If you need to relax, press the
<strong><u>S</u></strong>tress reliever!</p>

<button id="enter-btn">Stress reliever</button>
```

However what you're probably trying to recreate is the form action of submitting on enter, you can read more on the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Answer (score 1):

There is none.  Per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey), "The attribute value must consist of a single printable character". The enter key is not a printable character.

It is also already in use as a keyboard shortcut for several significant UX interactions by default; assigning it to other uses would conflict with those expected defaults.

(Note also that this [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/accessKey) "is seldom used because of its multiple conflicts with already present key bindings in browsers.")